# Subtract 2d array from every 2d element of a 3d array in Python-Convert Matlab code to Python

Tags: python, loops

I want to create following equation:

```
R = (I1-D)/(W-D)
```

Where I1 is a 3D array, and D, W are 2D arrays. I want D to iterate over the elements of I1 and then divide by the denominator and get a 3D array as a result (R). 
I have a Matlab code to do this and I want to convert it to Python.

```
 for i=1:size(I1,1)
 Numerator(i,:,:) = I1(i,:,:)-D;
 end

 Denominator = W-D;

 for i=1:size(Numerator,1)
 R(i,:,:) = Numerator(i,:,:) ./ Denominator ;
 end
```

The data is very large and I need to use for loops to do this. Is there any idea how to convert this to python?

Comment: What Python code did you try?

Comment: Are you using numpy?

Comment: The code here is in Matlab. I want to convert the code to Python. I don't have a code in Python yet, but I use numpy and pandas.